# Install TensorFlow with specific version on Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

TensorFlow has multiple [versions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/), if I want to install a specific version in Anaconda, which command should I use?

Answer (score 31):

I find the existing answers unsatisfying, as the OP asked specifically about Anaconda but the answers are just pip installs.

You can list the available versions for install doing

```
conda search tensorflow-gpu
```

which should give you some output that looks like

```
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
tensorflow-gpu                 1.4.1               0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow-gpu                 1.5.0               0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow-gpu                 1.6.0               0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow-gpu                 1.7.0               0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow-gpu                 1.8.0      h7b35bdc_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow-gpu                 1.9.0      hf154084_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow-gpu                1.10.0      hf154084_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow-gpu                1.11.0      h0d30ee6_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow-gpu                1.12.0      h0d30ee6_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow-gpu                1.13.1      h0d30ee6_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow-gpu                1.14.0      h0d30ee6_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow-gpu                1.15.0      h0d30ee6_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow-gpu                 2.0.0      h0d30ee6_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow-gpu                 2.1.0      h0d30ee6_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow-gpu                 2.2.0      h0d30ee6_0  pkgs/main
```

If you need to specify a particular channel, the `-c`/`--channel` option is your friend, for example:

```
conda search -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu
```

Then you can select your version by passing it to the install command, for example:

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0
```

If you needed the channel option in your search, you should add the same option to the `conda install` command. Note this will work the same for `tensorflow` (i.e. not the GPU version), just change the package name accordingly.

## YAML Configuration

If you use YAML environment configuration files, you can do the same thing:

```
# environment.yaml
name: my_conda_env
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - tensorflow-gpu=2.0.0
```

Create your environment with command:

```
conda env create -f environment.yaml
```

or if you change the version of an already created environment:

```
conda env update -f environment.yaml
```

Answer (score 15):

This is probably the simplest way to do it:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow==1.4
```

If you want to see all available versions, you can check out https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow/json

I would highly recommend you use `virtualenv` or `conda` to isolate your tensorflow installation, especially if you want to play-test different versions and the CPU/GPU versions.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you are using *Windows*, *python3.5*, and *CPU version* of tensorflow.

let's first create conda environment.

```
C:> conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5 
C:> activate tensorflow
 (tensorflow)C:>  # Your prompt should change
```

After creating the conda environment successfully, issue the correct command to install the specific version. I will guide you through installing three different versions.

To install version [`r1.0`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/install/install_windows)

```
(tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

To install version [`r1.3`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/install/install_windows)

```
(tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.3.0rc1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

To install [`master`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/install/install_windows) version

```
(tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

let me know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: Hi- How can I find wheel for r1.7 (py3.5). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To install specific version of python, tensorflow while creating conda environment:
conda create -n python=3.6 tensorflow=1.12.0

Answer (score 0):

I have a older project which has dependency to run on:

```
Python: 3.7 
Tensorflow: 1.13.1
```

For this I create a virutal environment using anancoda like:

```
conda create -n tf python=3.7 tensorflow=1.13.1 
// here more modules with specific version can be added
```

After that we to activate env:

```
conda activate tf
```

after this ouput was:

```
(tf) D:\ff\testM>
```

Environment changed from `(base) --> (tf)`

```
(base) D:\ff\testM>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a older project which has dependency to run on:

```
Python: 3.7 
Tensorflow: 1.13.1
```

To create i used ananconda:

```
conda create -n tf python=3.7 tensorflow=1.13.1 
// here more modules with specific version can be added 

conda activate tf //Activate environment

(base) D:\ff\testM>  --> (tf) D:\ff\testM> 
// environment changes from base to tf
```